# Laravel 4.2 - Returning Validation Errors to specific Form

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I have a login and register form always included in my master layout for each page.

Each of them are submitted to their respective routes (/login and /register) and have different validations for them. If the validation fails the controllers send them back to whatever page they were on with the following:

#### lets say that the validation failed for register

I've tried adding an alias to the errors

`return Redirect::back()-withErrors($validation,'register')`

I've also tried sending back another variable

`return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->with('errorsFor','register')`

at the top of my page inside a script tag

```
 @if(!(empty($errors)))
          //..pseudo code here
       @if(<TheVariable that specifies which form the errors are for> == 'register')
           //set error messages under the register form
           $("#registerForm").modal(); // <-- my forms are opened using bootstrap modal
       @elseif(<TheVariable that specifies which form the errors are for> == 'login')
          //set error messages under the login form
           $("#loginForm").modal(); // <-- my forms are opened using bootstrap modal
       @endif
 @endif
```

How do i send back an identifier to specify the form i want to set the errors for, as well as sending back the errors? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The `errors` variable that is given to the view is a collection of errors not a single error. In the collection, it should give you each input. So couldn't you check what inputs are in there and know which form it came from based on that?

Comment: I was browsing the internet but i couldn't find what you meant by searching for the inputs inside the `$error` collection. Is it something along the lines of Input::old?

Comment: How is your variable `$validation` defined, please share that part of code.

Comment: I can update this post later but i believe its something along the lines of: 
`$rules = array('username' => 'required|max:25','password'=>'required');`
`$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);`
Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation,'register');
```

seems to be okay, as you are specifying a *named error bag* for the `register` form, which can be done as well on the other form `login` as such:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation,'login');
```

Now to make sure whether a form has validation errors, you can check a condition like this:

```
   @if($validation->register)
       //set error messages under the register form 
       $("#registerForm").modal(); // <-- my forms are opened using bootstrap modal
   @elseif($validation->login)
      //set error messages under the login form
       $("#loginForm").modal(); // <-- my forms are opened using bootstrap modal
   @endif
```

To access a particular field error in a particular error bag, you can perform the following:

```
 $validation->register->first('field_name');
```

**[Laravel's Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#error-messages-and-views)**

**Note:** You don't need to do the way you've gone with the second part of your code:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->with('errorsFor','register')
```

since `with('errorsFor', 'register')` means you are passing the variable `$errorsFor` with the value `'register'`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help, this fixed the problem. I love you. :D

Comment: Welcome, don't forget the +1 and/or ACCEPT :)

Comment: I can't do +1 yet, i just joined stackoverflow so my reputation isnt over 15. But i did accept :)
I have another problem now gonna ask it soon tried looking and my code seems like it should work but it doesn't...

Comment: Looking forward to it, DO share the new question's link here somewhere so that I am notified of the problem.